# Embedded HTML5 player refuses fullscreen requests

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This is the whole page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/bitdash/latest/bitdash.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var conf = {
        key:       "xxxxxxx",
    playback: {
     autoplay:  true
    },
        source: {
          dash:        'http://xxxxxx',
          poster:      'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y5qYUsmZNHg/maxresdefault.jpg'
        }
    };
    var player = bitdash('player');
    if (player.requestFullscreen) {
    player.requestFullscreen(); }

    player.setup(conf).then(function(value) {
        // Success
        console.log('Successfully created bitdash player instance');
    }, function(reason) {
        // Error!
        console.log('Error while creating bitdash player instance');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I use a simple iframe embed code and even add allowfullscreen into it
however whenever I attempt to full screen it in by browser it returns the error

"Request for full-screen was denied because at least one of the document's containing iframes does not have an "allowfullscreen" attribute."

I am not well versed in JS or HTML so this is likely me being stupid. I added the if statement which did not fix it so I am lost here.

Comment: allowfullscreen is a boolean. Make sure it is set to true.

Comment: Where's the iframe in the code? Is this the page within the iframe?